# How to multiply a list of integers by one string in html?

Tags: javascript, html, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a list with integers that is coming from flask-sqlalchemy database. Im displaying these integers in a list with (li) tags. I wondering how I could take these integers and multiply them by "I". So the result would for example be: 5*"I", 6*"I" and that would display:

IIIII

IIIIII

in the list, instead of the showing as integers.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us any code that you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be looking for this built-in String method:

```
"I".repeat(5) // IIIII
"I".repeat(6) // IIIIII
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change your integer to 'I' marks. You can use some JQuery or JavaScript.

```js
let integers = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

integers.forEach(i=> {       
  $('#myList').append('<li>'+'I'.repeat(i)+'</li>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="myList">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, Im still having problem because the data from sqlalchemy isnt passed as a list. Im getting these errors:                                              
 let integers =  "39";
""
let integers =  "14";
""
let integers =  "46";
""
let integers =  "40";                                                                                              
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'integers' has already been declared

Comment: In my example "integers" is an array and you can not define same identifier in same scope more than once. 
If you want to use my examle, you can define an array and fill that array like 
let integers=[] 
integers.push(39)
integers.push(14)
integers.push(46)

Comment: Yes, But sqlalchemy is returning tuples instead of lists when doing data1.query.all(). I have to query sqlalchemy so I can get the integers to a list instead of tuples, but I dont know how I should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's built in `String.repeat` function along with `Array.map`.

```
var numList = [3,5,2,6,7,4,1,2]; // <-- what you get from database

var strList = list.map((e) => "I".repeat(e)); // <-- this is what you need 

console.log(is.join(",")); // prints "III,IIIII,II,IIIIII,IIIIIII,IIII,I,II"
```

**String.repeat**

> > The repeat() method constructs and returns a new string which contains the specified number of copies of the string on which it was called, concatenated together.
> >     
> >     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But Im having the same problem here, the sqlalchemy database isnt sent as a list with the jinja tags, so the variable in JS gets declared for every single number instead of [5,5,5] for example.